# Changing input method (language) works in Unity but not in Mate

Tags: unity, language-support, mate, input-method

I use Ubuntu 16.04 in English and Hebrew, and keep it up to date.
I started looking at alternate DE's and installed Mate.
In Unity changing between the languages works either by pressing  Alt + Shift or by clicking the input method icon and choosing which language I need.
In Mate it recognizes that I have Hebrew installed but does not change even the icon when I click Alt + Shift, and when pressing the icon and changing to Hebrew, the icon changes but nothing else does.
I can read Hebrew online just fine even in Mate.
What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if MATE is supposed to be different in this respect, but on Unity this terminal command can be used to set input method:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

The number **0** (zero) means that you set the first available input method. Change it to **1** to set the second etc.

Maybe worth a try on your MATE desktop.

*Edit:*

Installed MATE out of curiosity, and saw that it **is** different. Added an additional keyboard layout via *System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Layouts*, and encountered the same problem first. However, after having played around for a while, I could successfully switch keyboard layout. So maybe just relogin or reboot...

Comment: In 'gsettings'   there is no org.mate.desktop.input-sources.
I tried 'org.mate.interface' and got the reply: 'No such key "current"'.
Same for org.mate.applications-browser and org.mate.keyboard-peripherals. I looked at 'gsettings list-schemas' and tried the ones that looked likeliest.

Comment: @Uberhumus: Please see my edited answer.